# OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1129, "IP' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'")

Tags: python, mysql

I'm facing this issue while executing any query from my virtual server. I'm using aws rds and able to connect via mysql workbench and also able to execute queries as well but it's not working in python scripts.

```
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1129, "IP' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'")
```

And when I run this command `mysqladmin flush-hosts` it shows error and no command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are able to connect via MySQL workbench then try executing `FLUSH HOSTS;`. It will resolve your issue and try to fix all errors you were facing in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve just restarted MySQL server to fix this situation. It is not that elegant, but worked.

Comment: That is not a real solution. Please read about answers for stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer